# Disabling the Glass lambda cache

Tags: caching, performance-optimization, glass-mapper

I believe an issue we're running into might be related to the lambda cache in Glass - I'm also concerned about the performance ramifications if we were to disable it. Has anyone done this and experienced any performance issues?

Edit - this was the original issue:

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    at lambda_method(Closure , ContentBlurbViewModel )
    at Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml.MakeEditable[T](Expression`1 field, Expression`1 standardOutput, T model, Object parameters, Context context, Database database, TextWriter writer) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\GlassHtml.cs:line 616
```

Lambda(s) that this fails on:

```razor
@Html.Glass().Editable(a => a.Heading)
@Html.Glass().Editable(a => a.Subtitle)
@Html.Glass().Editable(a => a.RichText1)
```

All of these lambdas are in the same cshtml view and share a view model. It looks like somehow or another the proxy object is returning nulls for the properties and Editable starts failing and it gets cached.

Comment: What is the original issue?

Comment: Can you post the original lambda?

Comment: Updated the question with the issue - this would pop up randomly on the site and then would stay like that until we recycled the app pool.

Comment: Did this happen across all pages or just a single page?

Comment: A single page. Lambda is going up in the question.

Comment: Which version of Glass Mapper do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda seems correct, and there are no obvious reason for failure. I think the next step is to log this as a big on Github:

https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper

You can turn the lambda cache off using the following code in the GlassMapperScCustom class:

```cs
public static  class GlassMapperScCustom
{
    public static IDependencyResolver CreateResolver(){
        var config = new Glass.Mapper.Sc.Config();
        config.UseGlassHtmlLambdaCache = false;

        var dependencyResolver = new DependencyResolver(config);

        // add any changes to the standard resolver here
        return dependencyResolver;
    }
```

Another thing to try is wrapping your lambda's in a null check:

```razor
@if(Model != null){

   @Html.Glass().Editable(a=>a.Text)

}
```

Comment: Are there any performance concerns that need to be considered when disabling the lambda cache?

Comment: There will be a small decrease because every time you use the lambda it has to be compiled. I don't have exact numbers on the impact.